# Python. Applying an equation to all elements of 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, range

I am trying to apply an equation in python to all values of an array that are more or less reliant on the values behind it.
For example

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for i in range(len(b)):
 x =  b[i]+ b[i+1] - a[i] + a[i+1] .....
```

and so on and so Forth.
I am trying initially to display this as a value in an array and eventually as a sum.
where my expected outcome would be

```
[9, 27, 45, 63, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153]
```

I cant seem to get past the range function where it only displays a or b[i] as the last value of the array and uses that to calculate the equation such as using 10 or 100 and applying the equation as such.

Comment: Think about `for a1,a2,b1,b2 in zip(a[:-1], a[1:], b[:-1], b[1:] ):` / `x.append( b1+b2-a1-a2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of every pair of 2 of list b - the sum of every pair of 2 of list a is what you want to do, until the shortest list ends. You might want to append to the list if you require the list
 So this will be a simple working example:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for i in range(min(len(a),len(b))-2):
    x.append( sum(b[i:i+2])-sum(a[i:i+2]) )
```

Output:

```
[9, 27, 45, 63, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153]
```

Answer (score 0):

When examining the given equation, the variable `a[i]` corresponds to an element in the array `a`. However, the last element of `a` cannot be used for this calculation. To obtain a new array containing all elements of `a` except the last one, we can use the expression `a_i = a[:-1]`.

Similarly, the variable `a[i+1]` corresponds to an element one position ahead of `a[i]`. We can obtain an array containing all elements of `a` starting from the second element (i.e., skipping the first element) using the expression `a[1:]`. Thus we can do as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
a, b = np.array(a), np.array(b)
x = b[:-1] + b[1:] - a[:-1] - a[1:]
print(x)
print(a[:-1])
print(a[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answers are already provided in this thread. My answer shows that you can use recursion as well. BTW I think the answer should be

```py
[9, 27, 45, 63, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153, 171]
```

and not

```py
[9, 27, 45, 63, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153]
```

But I could be wrong. Please double check.

Here is a little different way.

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
ProcessedList = []
def func(a,b):
    if len(a)<2 and len(b)<2:
        return
    else:
        ProcessedList.append(b[0]+b[1]-a[0]-a[1])
        return func(a[1:],b[1:])

func(a,b)
print(ProcessedList)
```

ProcesedList is your answer. The output is

```py
[9, 27, 45, 63, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153, 171]
```

After @ThierryLathuille pointed out that you may run into maximum recursion depth issues, I suggest you take a look at other answers as well. You can solve it iteratively using below method as well.

```py
print(list(map(lambda x: b[x]+b[x+1]-a[x]-a[x+1], range(len(a)-1))))
```

Gives the same output

```py
[9, 27, 45, 63, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153, 171]
```

However this additional answer of mine is not much different than the answers already posted.

Comment: And this would fail with a recursion error when the list gets long enough - so not a good idea to convert this simple iterative problem into a recursive one...

Comment: Yes @ThierryLathuille, you are absolutely right ..the consumer of this code should understand the concept of recursion depth limit (maximum recursion depth). If the list is not very long, then this could be an alternate way. I just wanted to show that it is possible to solve this without iteration. Just to add something different.